# Failed to clone an exist mysql server using mysqlserverclone utilities

Tags: mysql, windows

I installed mysql server 5.7.12 utilities 1.5.6 using mysql installer for windows. I configed mysql-server through installer wizard. Then, I try to clone this server using mysqlcloneserver utilities:

```
mysqlserverclone --server=root:mysql@localhost:3306 --new-data="C:/Users/quyet/Documents/DBMS/fabric/store" --mysqld="--server-id=2 --log-bin --log-slave-updates --gtid-mode=ON --enforce-gtid-consistency" --new-port=13000 --delete-data
```

The command ouput this error after run the command:

```
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# WARNING: Root password for new instance has not been set.
# Cloning the MySQL server running on localhost.

The console has detected that the utility 'mysqlserverclone' ended with an error code.
You can get more information about the error by running the console command 'show last error'.
```

I run command:

```
show last error
```

and get this output:

```
Execution of utility: 'mysqlserverclone --server=root:mysql@localhost:3306 --new-data=C:/Users/quyet/Documents/DBMS/fabric/store --mysqld=--server-id=2 --log-bin --log-slave-updates --gtid-mode=ON --enforce-gtid-consistency --new-port=13000 --delete-data' ended with return code '1' and with the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\ade\build\sb_0-16486154-1442332453.92\Python-2.7.6-windows-x86-32bit\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "scripts\mysqlserverclone.py", line 211, in <module>
  File ".\mysql\utilities\command\serverclone.py", line 180, in clone_server
  File ".\mysql\utilities\common\tools.py", line 254, in get_mysqld_version
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'version_check'
```

I has searched on google but found any similar problems.
Any help will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

A bit outdated, but it might help.
Run Mysql Utils console as administrator